# Typing speed in Edittext is lag in some android phones

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my code the typing speed in EditText is slow. In some solutions i found that it will solve when the edittext is embedded inside a linearlayout and layout_width and layout_height of edittext changed to fill_parent. But it is not working. Please go through my xml code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/register_number" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:theme="@style/Logintheme"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/password" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/Logintheme"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
   </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

logintheme style code

```
 <style name="Logintheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

For any positive feedback thanks in advance

Comment: can you please post your style which is Logintheme.

Comment: <style name="Logintheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    </style>

Comment: I just copy and paste whole code in my studio and run the project. I didn't find any issue regarding lagging.

Comment: it is not in all devices... It have no lag in most of phones.. Asus zenphone have lag issue

Comment: samsung j5 also have same issue

Comment: Sorry but no issue with Samsung J5 I just tested this thing in J5, Htc Desire 820, LETv 2, redmi, nexus 5, nexus tab 7 no issue found I dont know about the Asus zenphone. But as u said J5 I didn't face any issue sir.

Comment: @ArjunBabu did you find a solution for this?